# Crop top and bottom of large circle

Tags: html, css, geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to make my homepage similar to my business card, seen here without the text: http://katiehambor.com/images/businesscardexample.png

I want the webpage to have this cropped circle to mimic my business card, and at almost any browser size the background image (diagonal stripes) will still be seen on the left and right.
Basically the top and bottom of the circle should be cropped and the left and right should be exposed so that the background image is shown (not shown on this codepen). I want it to be responsive so if someone makes their browser smaller, the circle will still be centered. I also do not want to be able to see the bottom of the circle, since right now if you scroll down you can see the bottom edge.

There will not be a lot of text in the circle, so there's no need to worry that all the text will fit inside.

I also want this site to be responsive so that for horizontal screens it will look like this, but on vertical screens the whole circle will probably be shown. I don't need to figure this out though because I know how to see the full circle, as my problem is with cropping the circle, but it's just something to keep in mind.

Also there will be a text div within the circle—right now it just says 'text' and I made it transparent for reference. I know this might need more divs to accomplish, but I don't really know where to go from here.

Please let me know if there's anything I can clear up about my question—sorry if it seems confusing!

**Edit:** Below is my first try, but it has been changed so it can now be seen [here](http://codepen.io/mezzotessitura/pen/Iecsk).

```
/*original on: http://codepen.io/mezzotessitura/pen/kfenK */

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Katie Hambor</title>

<style>
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
  background-size: auto;
  color: black;
}

.box {
     background-color:#00a886;
     padding:5px;

     top:-10%;bottom:0;left:15%;right:15%;
     width:55em;
     height:55em;
     position:absolute;
     border-radius:50%;
 }

.textbox {
    height:auto;
    margin:5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    background-color:#fff;
    opacity:.25;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
<div class="textbox">
<p>text</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer on Reddit [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/css/comments/2fheaz/help_crop_top_and_bottom_of_circle/ck9mde7).

> Uses `vw` to accomplish the responsive aspect. And transform for centering it (from this css-tricks article). I used `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`, but both do the same job in this case because `div.box` is positioned relative to the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

try `background-size:cover` on the body. but I would make it cross browser friendly.

```
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: how does this slightly relates to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This should work better for you. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/utkbF

Using css to create the circle:

```
.box{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:#00a886;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I want it to be a circle at all times, not an oval.